# updating rows till sum is matched?

Tags: php, mysql, math, currency

I have a table that looks like

**id**
Type: Auto inc-int
Comment: the unique id
Value Inserted auto inc int

**dateGained**
Type: dateTime
Comment: Date currency was gained
Value inserted: Current Date/Time

**amntGained**
Type: float
Comment: Amount of currency gained
Value inserted: value gained (e.g. 0.25)

**amntUsed**
Type: float
Comment: When part of the value is used this column gets updated
Value inserted: 0

**uuid**
Type: uuid
Comment: The users uuid
Value inserted: (a uuid)

so a few example rows (for a single user) would be

```
1 | 2010-07-30 00:00:00 | 0.25 | 0.20 | [uuid]  
2 | 2010-08-12 00:00:00 | 1.75 | 0.00 | [uuid]  
3 | 2010-08-17 00:00:00 | 8.25 | 0.00 | [uuid]  
4 | 2010-09-15 00:00:00 | 0.05 | 0.00 | [uuid]
```

Now my question is around the logic:

Basically I have a function that is given a uuid and an amount, the function then has to go through **starting from the oldest** and update the used value untill the amount given is satisfied.

e.g. if the function was given `6.25` and `[uuid]`

The table would look like

```
1 | 2010-07-30 00:00:00 | 0.25 | 0.25 | [uuid] //still need to use 6.20  
2 | 2010-08-12 00:00:00 | 1.75 | 1.75 | [uuid] //still need to use 4.45 
3 | 2010-08-17 00:00:00 | 8.25 | 4.45 | [uuid] //we now have 3.80 remaining 
4 | 2010-09-15 00:00:00 | 0.05 | 0.00 | [uuid] //this row is untouched
```

but I have a complete mind blank on how to do this efficiently or at all for that matter.

Comment: This resembles a transaction/log table to me, if I faced the same problem I would probably remodel and have another table containing the overall "balance", or similar solution. Not much help of course.

Comment: we actually have a transaction log as well, but the currency expires 6 months after it is gained, hence we need to also keep a log like this.. and because a user does not have to use the entire block of currency at once it becomes more difficult..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you?  (**Updated** version)

```
UPDATE table1 t3
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT t1.id, IFNULL(SUM(t2.amntGained),0) as total // 0 for the smallest date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON (t2.uuid = t1.uuid AND t2.dateGained < t1.dateGained)
// LEFT JOIN,not INNER because "<" is used for joining, 
WHERE uuid = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
)X  ON (X.id=t3.id)
SET t3.amntUsed = IF(X.total+t3.amntGained <=6.25, t3.amntGained, 
 IF(6.25-X.total>0, 6.25-X.total,0))
WHERE t3.uuid=1
```

For your  data:

```
id - total - amntGained - X.total+t3.amntGained - 6.25-X.total>0 - new.amntUsed
1  - 0     - 0.25      - 0.25                   - true             0.25
2  - 0.25  - 1.75      - 2                      - true             1.75
3  - 2     - 8.25      - 10.25                  - true             6.25-2 = 4.25
4  - 10.25 - 0.05      - 10.30                  - false            0
```